# Black, flat, modern emojis - Debian

Tags: debian, fonts, node.js, emoji

I have been trying to find a package that provides me with flat, black emojis to use in my node.js application.

I have tried `ttf-ancient-fonts` but the emojis don't look flat or modern

[image] [image]

Is there a package that has modern, black, flat emojis?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the only reason I mentioned `ttf-ancient-fonts` is because it's the only package I found that has flat, black emojis. I edited the post to include my question.

Comment: There is [Noto Emoji](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji#bw-emoji-font), albeit abandoned.

Comment: This might sound dumb but how do I install that?

Comment: Download [the font file](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/blob/master/fonts/NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf) and put it in `~/.fonts/`.

Comment: It didn't work, I have tried multiple ways of using the file. I didn't have `~/.fonts/` so I created it and downloaded the file into it. I also tried putting the file into `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto` and `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto`. When I installed `ttf-ancient-fonts` the last step of the installation process is `Processing triggers for fontconfig` so that's probably how I'd get the font file to work, I'm not sure how to manually do that though.

Comment: You may have had to run `fc-cache` to trigger a rescan on font directories.

Comment: I looked around for more information and it still doesn't work. I placed the file in `/usr/share/fonts/` and `/usr/local/share/fonts` and ran `sudo fc-cache -f -v` and got `/usr/local/share/fonts/emoji: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs` it says 0 fonts despite the file being in `/usr/local/share/fonts/emoji`.

Comment: Maybe the downloaded file is corrupted then? Does `fc-query` work on it?

Comment: I downloaded it multiple times while testing and my IDE was able to open it, didn't seem corrupt, `fc-query` outputs `Can't query face 0 of font file NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf`

Comment: The "can't query" error most likely indicates wrong permissions on the font file. Usually you shouldn't put font files in `/usr` and run `fc-cache` as root. I can advise you to check your font configuration files in `/etc/fonts` to make sure that user-specific font dirs are enabled and that there is no rule that replaces the noto emoji font for another. That being said, these are quite different and separate questions.